# Can you nest on click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a pomodoro clock with a break timer and a session timer. I'm using a single numpad to input the data into each clock by trying to nest the o'clock event to set each clock. To make it happen you click the display for the clock and then start inputting the buttons. There is 0-9 a delete button and an enter button. I haven't been able to get it to even display anything for either function. So I'm starting to wonder if what I'm trying to do would even work? Just looking for whether you can nest on click events and if so what I'm doing wrong. Or another method for what I'm looking to do. Made a fiddle to view it minimize the js and css windows. https://jsfiddle.net/zackluckyf/jhe98j05/1/

```
 $(".session-time-clock").click(function(){
            // changes the color to make it flash, add a duration and then change it back
            $(".num-button").css("background-color", "#BCC6CC");
            function myFunction() {
                myVar = setTimeout(changeBackground, 500);
            }
            function changeBackground() {
                $(".num-button").css("background-color", "#575e62");
            }
            myFunction();
            sessionTimeClock = "00:00";
            counter = 4;
        /*

        Will this work?

        */
        $("button").click(function(){
            // gets button text label
            var input = $(this).text();
            // if, else if chain for calculator functions
            if(input !== "Start" && input !== "Pause" && input !== "Reset" && input !== "X" && input !== "Enter" && counter > -1)
                {
                    if(counter === 4)
                        {
                            sessionTimeClock = sessionTimeClock.slice(0,counter-1) + input;
                        }
                    if(counter === 3)
                        {
                            sessionTimeClock = "00:" + input + sessionTimeClock.slice(4);
                        }
                    if(counter === 1)
                        {
                            sessionTimeClock = "0" + input + sessionTimeClock.slice(2);
                        }
                    if(counter === 0)
                        {
                            sessionTimeClock = input +  sessionTimeClock.slice(1);
                        }
                    counter--;
                    if(counter === 2)
                        {
                            counter--;
                        }
                }
            else if(input === "X")
                {
                    if(counter === 3)
                        {
                            sessionTimeClock = "00:0" + sessionTimeClock.slice(4);
                        }
                    else if(counter === 1)
                        {
                            sessionTimeClock = "00:" + sessionTimeClock.slice(3);
                        }
                    else if(counter === 0)
                        {
                            sessionTimeClock = "0" + sessionTimeClock.slice(1);
                        }
                }
            else if(input === "Enter")
                {
                    return;
                }
            $(".session-time-clock").text("hello");
        }); 
    });

    $(".break-time-clock").click(function(){
        $(".num-button").css("background-color", "#BCC6CC");
        function myFunction() {
            myVar = setTimeout(changeBackground, 500);
        }
        function changeBackground() {
            $(".num-button").css("background-color", "#575e62");
        }
        myFunction();
        breakTimeClock = "00:00";
        counter = 4;
        $("button").click(function(){
            // gets button text label
            var input = $(this).text();
            // if, else if chain for calculator functions
            if(input !== "Start" && input !== "Pause" && input !== "Reset" && input !== "X" && input !== "Enter" && counter > -1)
                {
                    if(counter === 4)
                        {
                            breakTimeClock = breakTimeClock.slice(0,counter-1) + input;
                        }
                    if(counter === 3)
                        {
                            breakTimeClock = "00:" + input + breakTimeClock.slice(4);
                        }
                    if(counter === 1)
                        {
                            breakTimeClock = "0" + input + breakTimeClock.slice(2);
                        }
                    if(counter === 0)
                        {
                            breakTimeClock = input +  breakTimeClock.slice(1);
                        }
                    counter--;
                    if(counter === 2)
                        {
                            counter--;
                        }
                }
            else if(input === "X")
                {
                    if(counter === 3)
                        {
                            breakTimeClock = "00:0" + breakTimeClock.slice(4);
                        }
                    else if(counter === 1)
                        {
                            breakTimeClock = "00:" + breakTimeClock.slice(3);
                        }
                    else if(counter === 0)
                        {
                            breakTimeClock = "0" + breakTimeClock.slice(1);
                        }
                }
            else if(input === "Enter")
                {
                    return;
                }
            $(".break-time-clock").text(breakTimeClock);
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: If you "nest" calls to .click() it simply means that the inner click handler will be assigned only when the outer click event occurs. *And*, if the outer click event occurs again an *additional* inner click handler will be assigned - which is rarely what you would actually want. (So relating that to your code, every time ".session-time-clock" is clicked, an *additional* click handler is added to "button" - and then when "button" is clicked, *all* of its click handlers will execute, one after the other, which will mess up your counter variable.)

Answer (score 0):

The supplied code is not identical to the jsfiddle. I will relate to the jsfiddle:

You have this code:

```js
    $("button").click(function(){
        if(input === "Start")
            {
                // start clock code
            }
        else if(input === "Pause")
            {
                // pause clock code
            }
        else if(input === "Reset")
            {
                sessionTimeClock = "00:00";
                breakTimeClock = "00:00";
            }
        return true;
    });
```

This is the first time you assign a click handler to "button" and therefore it gets called first.

The "input" variable is not defined, and therefore the other handlers are not called. (You can see an error in the Dev Tools console).